# Problem with brotli configuration in nginx

Tags: nginx, brotli

I am following this guide https://www.vultr.com/docs/add-brotli-support-to-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

I have followed every step but I am stuck at **Step 4 – Configure Nginx**

When I add to `nginx.conf`

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_static_module.so;
```

I get this error after running `sudo nginx -t`:

```
nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so" failed (/usr/share/nginx/modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:6
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

What might cause that?
Thank you!

Hosting provider: DigitalOcean
Server running: Ubuntu 20.04 LEMP
Nginx version: 1.17.10

Comment: it means there's no brotli module there, try to find the right path first

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue 2 years back and after a lot of reading and research got it working.
Hope this helps.
I have provided step by step instruction in the answer.

[ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so" is not binary compatible in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63388446/ngx-http-brotli-filter-module-so-is-not-binary-compatible-in-etc-nginx-nginx-c/64042532#64042532)